# JSP-html button enable-disable condition

Tags: javascript, jsp, button, enable-if

I tried some code to make disable-enable button by condition, but it apparently not working as I want:

```
<form method="get" action="reg.jsp">
    <%
        if ((String)session.getAttribute("dept") == "HR") {
    %>
        <th colspan="1"><input type="submit" value="Register"/></th>                           
    <% } 
        else {
    %> 
        <th colspan="1"><input type="submit" value="Register" disabled></th>
        <th><%= session.getAttribute("dept")%></th>
    <% 
        }
    %>
</form>
```

And it works like this:

button-unable

[image]

The "register" button supposed to be enable when the "department" is "HR".

Please help me to spot what I missed.. :(

Comment: Hi Rani. Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do so, just accept the answer below, so it has a tick mark - which I see you've done. Great! No need to add [solved] to titles - we prefer not to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Java code in your JSP. Use JSTL tags or JSP Expression language.

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Your markup can be much simplified using expression language as below:

```
<form method="get" action="reg.jsp">
    <th colspan="1">
         <input type="submit" value="Register" ${sessionScope.dept eq 'HR' ? '' : 'disabled' }/>
    </th>  
    <th>
         ${sessionScope.dept}
    </th>
</form>
```